# Autopostback resetting my list

Tags: c#, .net, button, controls, autopostback

I want to store items to a list but everytime i press the confirm button to add one item to the list the page will refresh and reset my list. How do i stop this from happening whilst at the same time have an add button to keep adding to the list?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        slist = (List<Shopping>)ViewState["Items"];
    }
}
```

List:

```
private static List<Shopping> slist;
        public List<Shopping> GetShopping()
        {
            return slist;
        }
```

Button Click:

```
slist = new List<Shopping>(); 
            Shopping s = new Shopping();
            s.Item1 = txtItem1.Text;
            s.Item2 = txtItem2.Text;
            s.Item3 = txtItem3.Text;
            s.Item4 = txtItem3.Text;

            slist.Add(s);
            ViewState["Items"] = slist;
            showShopping();
```

Method:

```
showShopping()
{
GridView1.DataSource = GetShopping();
            GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Use Session instead of ViewState and check if problem continues.

Comment: It still stores only one item to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store business objects in ViewState. Use the Session

```
private List<Shopping> ShoppingList
{
   get { 
          var shopping = Session["Shopping"] as List<Shopping>;
          if (shopping == null)
          {
              shopping = new List<Shopping>();
              Session["Shopping"] = shopping;
          }
          return shopping;
       }
   set { Session["Shopping"] = value; }
}
```

Button handler

```
var shopping = ShoppingList;
shopping.Add(new Shopping());
...
```

Comment: invalid expression term return?

Comment: @user had a return where there shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 1):

Stop building/binding the list on your page load without checking Page.IsPostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       // bind / load lists and controls here
    }
    else
    {
       //this is a post back, don't reload everything
    }
}
```

Edit *

Never do this if you ever want to support more then 1 shopper at a time.

```
private static List<Shopping> slist;
```

The users will end up writing over each others lists, then displaying the wrong one constantly. Remove the 'static' modifier.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                List = (List<Shopping>)ViewState["Items"];
            }
        } Will this not work?

Comment: Swap your code from the else clause to the If clause. Your logic is backwards.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into this with a debugger? You'd see the problem immediatley.

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same problem when I had the else statement

Comment: Are you binding the list to a control? Where?

Comment: In light of more information, I'd say Yads answer looks great.

Comment: Does it matter if its in a wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Been awhile since I have done WebForms, but it looks like you are assigning multiple items, but only one "Shopping" on the button click event then calling:

`showShopping() 
{ 
GridView1.DataSource = GetShopping();
GridView1.DataBind(); 
}`

Double check your GridView1 binding if you want the items to be displayed versus the Shopping object that you are binding to.

Comment: I have a subset of items stored to an object i want to add these items to a list, then equal a session to that list. I have declared my variables in the class using get set. Each set of items I want to put into a list as one set everytime I click "add button". So set 1 = item1, item2, item3, item4... add... another set of items and so fourth.

So it ends up like:
1 - item1, item2, item3, item4
2 - item1, item2, item3, item4
3 - item etc...

Each time pressing the add button

Comment: @user603605 Are you trying to display the items in the set? When you said "It still stores only one item to the list" @Pabuc are you referring to the set only has one item in it or that the GridView is only displaying the set and no items in the set?

Comment: here this plan will explain things better:
http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/7876/screen1pi.png